# Detecting OrientationChanged Event in Portrait Mode

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

On Windows Phone 8.1, I am doing an `OrientationChanged` event where a media element will change to full window when in landscape mode which works perfectly. But when I rotate to portrait, it doesn't back out of full window to its width of the screen in portrait mode.  In fact, it doesn't do anything. The problem is that the Event Handler detects the landscape orientation but not the portrait orientation? What am I missing? MediaElement seems stuck in `IsFullWindow = true` and never checks again for orientationchanged event method.

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="250" Background="Green" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MediaElement x:Name="media"
                  Source="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
                  AutoPlay="True"
                  AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Stretch="UniformToFill"
                  Width="Auto"
                  Height="Auto"
                      />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
void MainPage_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
{
    var orientation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().CurrentOrientation; // get the current orientation of the display
    if (orientation == DisplayOrientations.Landscape || orientation == DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped) // if the orientation is landscape...
    {
        media.IsFullWindow = true; // puts the media element in full screen while in landscape
    }
    else //if (orientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait || orientation == DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped)
    {
        media.IsFullWindow = false; // puts the media element out of full screen in portrait
        //media.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width; // set bounds of video width to width of screen
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Phone 8.1 or Silverlight 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

In your XAML you can write these lines of XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MediaElement x:Name="media"
                    Source="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
                    AutoPlay="True"
                    AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Stretch="Uniform" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In your code-behind you can call the OrientationChanged event of *SimpleOrientationSensor* class:

```
namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

            SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault().OrientationChanged += (s, a) =>
                Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                () =>
                {
                    if (a.Orientation == SimpleOrientation.NotRotated || a.Orientation == SimpleOrientation.Faceup || a.Orientation == SimpleOrientation.Facedown)
                    {
                        media.IsFullWindow = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        media.IsFullWindow = true;
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include *Windows.Devices.Sensors* reference ;)

Comment: Tested on Lumia 920 device directly.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm also receiving a warning message stating `Because this call is not awaited execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.` Should I be worried? How do I get rid of this warning?

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight don't worry about the await warning (that's because I put the method inside constructor :P). Did you test on a device or just on a Emulator? In real phone works for me. FaceUp or Down is not really necessary here.

Comment: Okay. Tested on my Lumia 1020 and still doesn't rotate back to portrait mode.

Comment: Another helpful insight: I also noticed the code in my post above, when media sets `IsFullWindow = true;`, It doesn't recognize or respond to `OrientationChanged` event. When media set `IsFullWindow = false;`, it respond to portrait and landscape roration. Is there a way to force it to come out of full window when rotation changes occur?

Comment: Width=" * " and Height=" * " for Grid does that work. HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" for StackPanel helps to rearrange your control.